# Can I pass a sharepoint security context value to a reporting services report parameter?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

I'm considering using reporting services 05 SP2 with share point integration on a new reporting project.

In this project's reports users can only see records they own. I was thinking a simple userId parameter on the report would allow me to filter the report's results to only these "owned" records.

I'm curious: Can I pass the current share point user's ID to the report some how? Can it be done in such a way that its not possible for the user to somehow alter it? How would I do this if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sharepoint UserID = the one RS will use and detect.
This is defined by UserID global in RS and picked up form the login token.

You can hide the parameter (Report) or just specify it at the dataset level (SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting row level security happening at the database end?

You project then only needs to pass the users credentials through as it does anyway and you can then let SQL server security handle the issue?